# Replacing text over an Image using Kinetic.js html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, replace, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I need to replace some text on the Image ,
not clear the canvas as I don't want to lose the image I just want to be able to replace the text on that Image from an input box outside of the canvas..and also add functionalities like change color,font,size of that Image.
I tried text plugin available in kineticjs form but it doesn't meet my requirement and I'm not able to understand it.
So any idea about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it; you could go about creating the image and the text is different layers and only recreate the text layer. Also long as you make sure the text layer is added to the stage last you will see this text.